# R - Create data set showing the delta/progress between two similar data sets

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data sets, snapshots of records taken at two different time periods. Each record has a unique key (Player.ID). There is identifying information that needs to be carried forward (Alliance.ID, Alliance.Tag, Player.ID, Player) with all of the remaining attributes needing to be evaluated for change over time (all new data points minus all old data points) producing a new, third data set. Lastly, we need to account for new players(all stats set to NEW) and deleted players (all stats set to MISSING).

Each data set has about 60,000 records.

[Three data sets; old, new, calculated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdEnK.png)

I have no code to share. Any advice on approach, packages or code is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df1$Source <- "df1"
df2$Source <- "df2"

output <- bind_rows(df1,df2) %>%
  group_by(Player.ID) %>%
  mutate(
    DATE = as.Date(DATE,tryFormats = c("%m/%d/%Y")),
    ROW.COUNT = n(),
    POINTS = case_when(
      ROW.COUNT == 1 & Source %in% "df1" ~ "Missing",
      ROW.COUNT == 1 &
        Source %in% "df2" ~ "NEW",
      ROW.COUNT >  1 ~ as.character(as.numeric(POINTS) - lag(as.numeric(POINTS), order_by = DATE)),
      TRUE ~ "ERROR"
    ),
    POWER.POINTS = case_when(
      ROW.COUNT == 1 & Source %in% "df1" ~ "Missing",
      ROW.COUNT == 1 &
        Source %in% "df2" ~ "NEW",
      ROW.COUNT >  1 ~ as.character(as.numeric(POWER.POINTS) - lag(as.numeric(POWER.POINTS), order_by = DATE)),
      TRUE ~ "ERROR"
    ),
    PLAYERS.KILLED = case_when(
      ROW.COUNT == 1 & Source %in% "df1" ~ "Missing",
      ROW.COUNT == 1 &
        Source %in% "df2" ~ "NEW",
      ROW.COUNT >  1 ~ as.character(as.numeric(PLAYERS.KILLED) - lag(as.numeric(PLAYERS.KILLED), order_by = DATE)),
      TRUE ~ "ERROR"
    )
  ) %>% 
  filter(DATE == max(DATE)) %>%
  select(-DATE,-Source,-ROW.COUNT)
```

Data

```
df1 <- structure(
  list(
    DATE = c("12/18/2020","12/28/2020"),
    Alliance.ID = c("9745908","8798794"),
    Alliance.Tag = c("StkOvflw","ILoveR"),
    Player.ID = c("z90c0b60dd58","grfk349i342k3"),
    PLAYER = c("Deanna","Gregor"),
    LVL = c(89,22),
    RANK = c("Admiral","Newb"),
    POINTS = c("16746162","19269094"),
    POWER.POINTS = c("77083200","87691376"),
    PLAYERS.KILLED = c("7337","4698")
  ),
  .Names = c(
    "DATE",
    "Alliance.ID",
    "Alliance.Tag",
    "Player.ID",
    "PLAYER",
    "LVL",
    "RANK",
    "POINTS",
    "POWER.POINTS",
    "PLAYERS.KILLED"
  ),
  row.names = c(NA, -2L),
  class = "data.frame"
)

df2 <- structure(
  list(
    DATE = c("1/4/2021","1/4/2021"),
    Alliance.ID = c("9745908","5874162"),
    Alliance.Tag = c("StkOvflw","NewGuy"),
    Player.ID = c("z90c0b60dd58","2387hyf23u8i4"),
    PLAYER = c("Deanna","NewGuy"),
    LVL = c(90,1),
    RANK = c("Admiral","Newb"),
    POINTS = c("16786133","1254"),
    POWER.POINTS = c("77089878","0"),
    PLAYERS.KILLED = c("7368","3")
  ),
  .Names = c(
    "DATE",
    "Alliance.ID",
    "Alliance.Tag",
    "Player.ID",
    "PLAYER",
    "LVL",
    "RANK",
    "POINTS",
    "POWER.POINTS",
    "PLAYERS.KILLED"
  ),
  row.names = c(NA, -2L),
  class = "data.frame"
)
```

Comment: Thank you so very much @Ritz735. I adapted your code for all the attributes (my sample was much smaller), and it worked beautifully. df1 has 47,918 records, df2 had 58,489 records, and the output had 58,544 records. The whole thing processed in about 2 minutes. I can live with that. I really appreciate the help.